# Only getting one set of values looping through and array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm using this code to try to loop through an array in PHP

```
$url='https://api.hubapi.com/form-integrations/v1/submissions/forms/e053ea53-0dae-4cbb-8343-f4ad7bbcaecd?hapikey=8b9998be-1082-4520-a503-c981bab5c57f';
$result = file_get_contents($url);
$arrays = json_decode($result,true);

foreach($arrays['results'][0]['values'] as $item) {
    echo $item['value'];
   
}
```

I'm only getting one set of values when there should be two

Output: GermanyADP, ECM IntroPMI Document Solutions, Inc.Munichhttp://www.pmi-ny.comOctober 241200Webinarthis is a testbob@hotmail.comLink to partner event

These are the second set of values. Where is the first?

Comment: `$arrays['results'][0]` only takes the first

Comment: If I remove the [0] I get a blank screen

Comment: Looks as though you need to loops, one at `results` level and another at `values`

Comment: Use `foreach($arrays['results'] as $result)` and then another `foreach` inside to loop the values

Comment: "_These are the second set of values. Where is the first?_" That is in fact the _first_ set, the second (United States ...) is missing

Comment: Nigel's answer got me on the right track. I got both sets to print. brombeer thank you too. Is there a way to get each values as a variable to move around the table cells?

Comment: I hope you didn't post live form with actual API key

Answer (score 0):

You can process the json data like this:

```
$url='https://api.hubapi.com/form-integrations/v1/submissions/forms/e053ea53-0dae-4cbb-8343-f4ad7bbcaecd?hapikey=8b9998be-1082-4520-a503-c981bab5c57f';
$json = json_decode( file_get_contents( $url ) );
$res=$json->results;

foreach( $res as $obj ){
    $values=$obj->values;
    
    foreach( $values as $o ){
        echo $o->name . ' ' . $o->value . ' ' . $o->objectTypeId . '<br />';
    }           
}
```

Which will output:

```
country Germany 0-2
title_no_dropdown ADP, ECM Intro 0-1
presented_by PMI Document Solutions, Inc. 0-1
city Munich 0-1
website http://www.pmi-ny.com 0-1
start_date October 24 0-1
time 1200 0-1
type Webinar 0-1
description this is a test 0-2
email bob@hotmail.com 0-1
link Link to partner event 0-1
country United States 0-2
title_no_dropdown ADP, Work Smart from the Start 0-1
state NY 0-1
presented_by PMI Document Solutions, Inc. 0-1
city Corning 0-1
website http://www.pmi-ny.com 0-1
start_date September 24 0-1
time 1000 0-1
type Infoseminar 0-1
description This is a test 0-2
email likwid2@hotmail.com 0-1
link Link to partner event 0-1
```

Comment: Excellent Professor Abronsius. Is there a way to get each value as a variable so I can move the order around in table cells?

Comment: I guess you can generate dynamic variables but the names might be an issue... or create your own array/object and use that somehow in your `"table"`

Comment: How would I use my own array/object in the "table"?

Comment: How long is a piece of string? The question you ask is without bounds or quantifiers - it is un-answerable. Ask  a new question with specific programming problems